# Kubuntu 18.04 windows go below the task-bar

Tags: kubuntu

I have a kubuntu 18.04. It works fine on the laptop. However, when the external monitor is connected the windows on the main laptop screen extend to the full screen and, on the bottom, go *under* the task-bar.

For example, they go from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: It would appear that the external monitor is lower resolution that the laptop monitor.

Comment: Actually higher. Setting the resolution the same fixes the issue. Setting the same and then back higher - also fixes.

Comment: I should have noted in my prior post that resolutions should be the same if possible

Answer (score 0):

Had this back when I used to push video to a TV. On Ubuntu. Finally found a replacement for the unity Gui that actually supported varying monitor aspects per monitor. Think it was called Mint in some way. Supposedly based on the Mint Linux shell style. Tricky to get setup but rock solid and so useful. Worth the effort.